# Каков максимальный размер пакета RTP при передачи по протоколу TCP/UDP

Tags: tcp, udp, ethernet, rtp, mtu

У меня появился вопрос, каков максимальный размер пакета `RTP` возможен, при передаче его по протоколу `TCP` или `UDP`, так как в стандарте [RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) про это ничего не сказанно. В некоторых **stackoverflow** ответах было [сказанно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097580/rtp-packet-maximum-size), что это - **1458** байт, но разве при передаче `RTP` пакета по `TCP` или `UDP`, этот размер не **~65535** (например, для `TCP`, это значение = `MAX_TCP_PACKET_SIZE - MIN_TCP_HEADER_SIZE` = `65535 - 20` = `65515`).

Мне нужен этот ответ, чтобы я знал, до какого размера полученного пакета я могу получить потенциальный пакет `RTP`. Также было бы здорово узнать, какие **`+`** и **`-`** при отправке максимального размера пакета по `TCP` и `UDP`.

Comment: Отправлять пакеты размером больше чем MTU (обычно 1500 байт) нерационально: в лучшем случае они будут фрагментированы, в худшем случае они вообще отфильтруются каким-нибудь роутером по дороге и не дойдут до адресата. Плюс резервируем место под технические заголовки и получаем что-то около 1458 байт

Comment: @andreymal, я полностью с Вами согласен, но если мы проигнорируем все нюансы отправки пакетов `RTP` с размером больше размера `MTU`, то каков же этот размер теоретически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65535 - это максимальный размер пакета в ipv4 (там просто два байта, больше не втулить). Такие пакеты без проблем ходят, если это localhost.

Если же выходим в локальную сеть, то максимальный размер udp пакета на самом деле такой же, но только пакет будет фрагментироваться (делится на куски). Это определяется размером MTU и обычно находится в диапазоне 1450-1500. Но каждый протокол съедает пару байт, к примеру, vpn может забрать 8 байт. Так как для UDP пакета доставка не гарантируется и он может потеряться, то для больших пакетов (больше MTU) шансы потеряться сильно выше - запросов на потерянный кусок нет и полученные куски просто будут выброшены. Если шансы потерять один кусок равны 0.9, то шансы потерять пакет с трех кусков уже 0.9^3 = 0.73. Ну и так далее.

Как только выходим в мировую сеть, все стает ещё печальнее. Пакеты упаковываются и перепаковываются, по дороге могут быть роутеры разного пошиба. и максимальный гарантированный размер пакета, который не будет фрагментироваться равен  576 байт (или  1280 байт для IPv6).

Считаем. Размер ip заголовка от 20 до 60 байт. udp заголовок - 8 байт. rtp, если правильно интерпретировал rfc, от 12 байт (самый минимум). Поэтому, минимум 40 байт на различные заголовки. Поэтому, 536 байт, как по мне - самый максимальный размер пакета, который гарантированно пролезет везде.

На практике, некоторые системы используют "примерку" - просто шлют udp пакеты разного размера и смотрят.